# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ask access to data on Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have really simple line of code called from button in menu:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Problem is, this line of code invokes message:

> "...needs your permission to access your data on Google"

And that's what makes me sad. I don't want to access data on Google. I just want to edit one sheet of data. This message will confuse all my colegues.

Is there a way how to restrain SpreadsheetApp to use only opened sheet ? How to avoid this message?

Maybe it doesn't look like problem, but saying user that I want to access his data isn't safe practise.

Thanks a lot

Jakub

Comment: I agree with your concern.  There is no way to avoid this message.  Someone at Google would need to change the wording of that message.  The only thing you can do is enter a feature request in the Issue Tracker:  [Link to Issue Tracker - Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)  If you want to promote support for your request, then you could post information in the Apps Script group:  [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Thanks for advice ! I'm on it.

Answer (score 4):

In the end what saved my day was this comment placed on top:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

That invokes message:

> View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed
>   in

So that's it.
More info here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_for_sheets_docs_and_forms